# Vacuum manifold and fermion condensation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, vacuum, ground-state, moduli

Vacuum manifold is just another name for the manifold spanned by the ground states of quantum field theory. It is also called moduli space.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_manifold, they said:

"the vacuum manifold is parameterized by the values of permissible vacuum expectation values. This is not the case for spontaneous symmetry breaking due to fermion condensation, though."

> question: why spontaneous symmetry breaking? why fermion condensation? make the vacuum manifold is NOT parameterized by the values of permissible vacuum expectation values?

> When, what else situations, and how the vacuum manifolds are NOT parameterized by the values of permissible vacuum expectation values?

Note that the bilinear fermion condensations induce a higgs boson like condensation, too (like the **technicolor** kind of idea).